# Exclude Specific Records from GLM?

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I've built a GLM model that basically says the following:

```
glm(conversion ~ action, data = data, family = "binomial"(link="logit")
```

Some of the results from the variable "action" aren't relevant to the model (i.e. "Did not use"). However, in the other models I've built, those records are still important. I don't want to filter my data frame just for this one model if at all possible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580379/how-do-i-exclude-specific-variables-from-a-glm-in-r) tells me how to exclude columns. Is there a way to exclude specific records from GLM in the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subset` argument that many of the modelling functions in R have. For example:

```
glm(conversion ~ action, data = data, family = binomial(),
    subset = action != "Did not use")
```

will fit the model to the data set after removing rows where `action == "Did not use"`. If you have additional levels in `action` to drop, you might use

```
glm(conversion ~ action, data = data, family = binomial(),
        subset = !action %in% c("Did not use", "Other"))
```

which will exclude any rows where `action` is equal to either of the supplied options.

You might also want to look at the `drop.unused.levels` argument to `model.frame`, which is the function that will act on any `subset` argument you supply to `glm()`.

PS: note how I have specified the `family`; you don't need to do the weird combination of quoting. one of `binomial`, `binomial()` or `"binomial"` should be fine as the logit link is the canonical link for the binomial family and hence it is the default in R's `bionmial()` family function. If you want to specify the link, use this form: `binomial(link = "logit")`.